# Duplicate autodividers when selecting from sqlite - jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, jquery-mobile

```
transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDER BY date DESC', [],
         function(transaction, result) {
         if (result != null && result.rows != null) {
         for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
         var row = result.rows.item(i);
         $('#records').append('<li date = "'+row['date']+'" data-rowid2="' + row['Id'] + '"><a href ="#">' + 'test: ' + row['column1'] + '</a></li>').trigger('change');
         }
         }
         },errorHandler);


transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Table2 ORDER BY date DESC', [],
         function(transaction, result) {
         if (result != null && result.rows != null) {
         for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
         var row = result.rows.item(i);
         $('#records').append('<li date = "'+row['date']+'" data-rowid="' + row['Id'] + '"><a href ="#">'+ 'Test2: ' + row['column1'] +'</a></li>').trigger('change');
         }
         $("#records").listview().listview("refresh");
         }
         },errorHandler);
         },errorHandler,nullHandler);
```

This is some code which selects columns from 2 different tables.  The tables have two different columns called date which stores the date input.  Notice the date attribute assigned to the li elements.  My problem comes here:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#mypage", function(){
           $("#records").listview({
                                  autodividers: true,
                                  autodividersSelector: function (li) {
                                  var out = li.attr("date");
                                  return out;
                                  }
                                  }).listview("refresh");
           });
```

Now since the dates are from two different tables, two autodividers are being created even if they share the same date.  For example if table1 date column had 2014-01-02 and table2 date column had 2014-01-02, two separate dividers would be created for the same date and the list elements wouldn't be shown under one.  Is there a solution to this problem?

NOTE:  Both the select statements append results to the same listview, they are just from different tables

EDIT:  I think I have found what the issue is, but I am not sure on how to solve it.  Basically, when I append those list elements, Table1 stuff takes priority and always goes first.  For example if I had the list like this:

```
Table 1 item
Table 2 item
```

Then if I added another Table 1 item it will do this:

```
Table 1 item
Table 1 item
Table 2 item
```

Which is displacing the table 2 item from its original position.  Is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: I believe for autodividers to work the listitems must be sorted.  Can you combine the query results from the 2 tables into one array of objects and then sort that array before adding the items to a listview? See this example for sorting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript

Comment: I'm a very inexperienced programmer, if that is the only way to do it, then I will just remove the autodivider feature.  I would try it, but my project is due soon